# Visualizar imagenes en Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Soy nuevo usando vue, estoy haciendo ejemplos usando Vue 2.0, tengo esta estructura

```
-src
 - assets
    --> logo.png
 - components
    --> beging.vue
```

estoy haciendo cambios en beging.vue y tengo esta linea

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
     <h1>Página de Inicio</h1>
     <hr>
     <img :src="require('../assets/logo.png')">
   </div>
</template>
```

El problema es que en el momento en que hago la compilación y publico esto en mi servidor local la imagen siempre está oculta pero antes de compilar puedo ver la imagen bien.

Esta es la estructura que tengo en mi servidor local

```
- assets
- dist
 .htaccess
- index.html
```

En teoria todo lo necesario existe dentro de la carpeta dist:

- build.js
- build.js.map
- logo.png

Pero la imagen nunca aparece. ¿Podrían ayudarme a comprender cuál es el problema?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Amigo, te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask], 
[mre], 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado

Comment: ¿Qué versión de vue estás usando? ¿`<img src="@/assets/logo.png"/>` no te funciona?

Comment: Arriba en la descripcion estoy mencionando la version de vue : /

Answer (score 0):

me imagino que el problema reside en tu configuracion de Vue o webpack, intenta dejar de usar el `v-bind` en el atributo de `src` dentro de la etiqueta de `<img>` y busca la imagen como `<img src="./assets/logo.png">` para validar que se despliegue tanto en tu ambiente local y como tu servidor, a no ser que hayas configurado [Assets Modules de Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/). De hecho el template por defacto que trae CodeSandbox es algo asi como te lo menciono, puedes revisar este [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-cloud-4wvcd) y tomarlo como ejemplo.